# When are parentheses required around a tuple?

Tags: python, syntax, tuples

Is there a reference somewhere defining precisely when enclosing tuples with parentheses is or is not required?

Here is an example that surprised me recently:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d[0,] = 'potato'
>>> if 0, in d:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if 0, in d:
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I find it especially interesting that `for k, in d: print k` does work in that case.

Comment: The [Python grammar](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html) will show you what *is* allowed, for example, in an `if` statement. You'd have to read over the full grammar to figure out where unparenthesized tuples are accepted, which is why I'm not posting this as an answer.

Comment: ...I fail to understand how you could have been *surprised* by the `for` failing with `0,`... python identifiers must start with a (unicode)letter or underscore and `0` is not a valid python identifier hence I would have *expected* a `SyntaxError` there.

Comment: That's why David said `for k,` not `for 0,` (It works i.e. it successfully does tuple unpacking into `k` for the case where the dict keys are 1-element tuples)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The combining of expressions to create a tuple using the comma token is termed an [`expression_list`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists).  The rules of [operator precedence](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) do not cover expression lists; this is because expression lists are not themselves expressions; they become expressions when enclosed in parentheses.

So, an unenclosed `expression_list` is allowed anywhere in Python that it is specifically allowed by the language grammar, but *not* where an `expression` as such is required.

For example, the grammar of the [if statement](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement) is as follows:

```
if_stmt ::=  "if" expression ":" suite
             ( "elif" expression ":" suite )*
             ["else" ":" suite]
```

Because the production `expression` is referenced, unenclosed `expression_list`s are not allowed as the subject of the `if` statement.  However, the [for statement](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) accepts an `expression_list`:

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]
```

So the following is allowed:

```
for x in 1, 2, 3:
    print(x)
```

Comment: +1 That certainly explains why `for k, in d` works (because `for k, v in d` works).

Comment: Question: Should you write it `for x in 1, 2, 3:` or `for x in (1, 2, 3):`? I've always written it the second way, but that was because I didn't know the first way was valid until just now when I tried. Now I'm wondering if the `()` are unnecessary noise, or if they somehow help in reading the code. Does PEP8 provide any guidance on this?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare there's no specific guidance in PEP8. It might help to compare with `if` statements, where parentheses are recommended only for a condition that spans multiple lines. So: `for x in (1, <newline> 2, <newline> 3):`.

Answer (score 19):

Anywhere you are allowed to use the [`expression_list`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists) term, you do not need to use parenthesis.

The [`if` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement) requires an `expression`, and does not support an `expression_list`.

Examples of syntax that does allow `expression_list`:

- The [`return` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement)
- [`yield` expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions)
- [assignment](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)
  (including [augmented assignment](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements))
- The [`for` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement).

Grepping the [Expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html), [Simple](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html) and [Compound statements](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html) documentation for `expression_list` will tell you all locations that `expression_list` is used in the Python grammar.

Comment: Oh yeah? How about `1,2,3 + 4,5`? It doesn't result in the expression list you might expect...

Comment: @smci what has that got to do with my answer? What outcome did you expect?

Comment: Because `1,2,3 + 4,5` results in the expression `1,2,7,5`, which is not what a casual reader would expect, and comes from overloading `+` for sequence append.

Comment: @smci sorry, but `1, 2, 7, 5` is *exactly* what I'd expect. Each part between commas is an expression; the whole is an `expression_list`. There is no grammar rule that sums expression lists; instead `+` is part of one of the contained expressions (`3 + 4`). To add up two tuples, make two separate expressions by adding parentheses.

Comment: Yes I know that. However, non-Python users or people who missed the lack of trailing comma would expect a concatenated tuple `1,2,3, + 4,5,` . What a difference the trailing comma makes.

Comment: @smci: By adding in a comma you turned the expression to `+4`, which is just `4`. You are still not concatenating two tuples, you are defining **one** tuple with the `+4` producing `4`.

Comment: Martijn I knew that when I posted it; I intentionally posted it to make the point that there can be cases of (in this case, visual) ambiguity, and in that case parenthesizing is highly recommended. I wasn't asking you to explain it, just making the point that ambiguity can exist.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses are also required when you want **to avoid ambiguity**.

The following are two different expressions... just because something is an 'expression list', doesn't result in the expression list you might expect :)

```
(1, 2, 3) + (4, 5) # results in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) because + does sequence.extend on the tuples
1, 2, 3 + 4, 5     # this results in (1, 2, 7, 5) because + adds the elements, since there were no parentheses to protect the separate tuples
```

Comment: Same as `1+2+3 * 4+5`. The result is perfectly clear when you know the operator precedence in Python. Using additional parentheses is not necessary here but helps those new in Python (or in math).

Comment: @Jeyekomon: No, you're missing the point: [Python operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Expressions) differs from [C/C++ operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) which differs from [Java operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax#Operators) etc. These ambiguities can and do cause even an extremely experienced programmer to make mistakes. Python does not exist in a vacuum. Every week on SO you can see such posts by (experienced) programmer proving this.