# Forcing a type to be a tuple

Tags: python, syntax

I'm new to Python and it took me some time to realize, in an auto-generated code this syntax means integer, not tuple:

```
(1)
```

In contrast `[1]` is still an array. Looks like a inconsistency in syntax :-(

However, is there a possibility to force `(1)` be a tuple?

**EDIT:**

Seems to be obvious for those who gave me - points. I wonder, why I didn't come across it till now.

In fact, the book I've bought for learning Python - **"Learning Python, O'Reilly, Mark Lutz, 5th Ed."** tells me on the **page 121**, Chapter Tuples:

> Syntactically, they are normally coded in parentheses instead of
>   square brackets...

and the first example that follows defines a tuple like this:

```
>>> T = (1, 2, 3, 4)    # A 4-item tuple
```

It's embarrassing, this book got so many stars on Amazon. I'm currently on the page 160 of 1500. Should I stop reading it?

Comment: related :  http://stackoverflow.com/q/16017811/674039

Comment: @wim: As a beginner I don't understand a word either in that question nor in the answers. However It seems like the comma alone is not always sufficient and conflicts with other syntaxes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put a comma:

```
>>> (1,)
(1,)
>>> type((1,))
<type 'tuple'>
>>>
```

`(1)` is just the integer `1` in parenthesis:

```
>>> (1)
1
>>>
```

This is because it is the *comma* that creates a tuple, not the parenthesis (if any):

```
>>> 1,
(1,)
>>> 1, 2, 3
(1, 2, 3)
>>> a = 1, 2, 3
>>> b = (1, 2, 3)
>>> a == b
True
>>>
```

Note however that you do need parenthesis to create an empty tuple:

```
>>> ()
()
>>> type(())
<type 'tuple'>
>>>
```

Although it could be argued that it is the *absence* of the comma that creates the tuple in this case. ;)

---

It is true that the comma creates a tuple, but I should have been more clear.

You are right that in `[1,2,3]`, the commas are not interpreted as a tuple because the square brackets on each end denote a list literal.

The comma in Python has four uses:

1. Creating a tuple literal, as I demonstrated above.
2. Separating items in a list/dict/set literal:

   ```
   [1, 2, 3]       # List

   {'a':1, 'b':2}  # Dict

   {1, 2, 3}       # Set
   ```
3. Separating arguments in function calls:

   ```
   func(a, b)
   ```
4. Separating names in various statements:

   ```
   import a, b

   global a, b

   nonlocal a, b

   with a as b, c as d:

   try:
       ...
   except (a, b):
   ```

   and iterable unpacking:

   ```
   a, b, c = [1, 2, 3]
   ```

Only in the first case is the comma interpreted as creating a tuple.  The other three uses simply reuse the `,` character to mean something different.

Comment: _it is the comma that creates a tuple, not the parenthesis_ -  When I think once again about the statement, it can't be entirely true. That would mean `[1,2,3]` is an array of one tuple `1,2,3`. However the point with additional comma helped me.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz - I have explained better in my edit.  Also, the book you are reading is fine.  I think that it just used parenthesis because they are common albeit unnecessary.  `T = 1, 2, 3, 4` would yield the same result.  The purpose of books like yours is to teach you Python.  I don't think it is concerned with intricate grammar rules like this.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an inconstency in the syntax: what makes a tuple is the comma, not the parens, and the minimal syntax for a litteral tuple is:

```
my_tuple = 1,
```

The parens are only needed for an empty tuple.

Comment: @iCodez: yes, it could ;)

Comment: _what makes a tuple is the comma, not the parens_ - as already mentioned in the comment for iCodez' answer: `[1,2,3]` would mean array having one tuple `(1,2,3)`. So comma alone seems to be not sufficient.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz: And ? You could also state that 'somefunc(1, 2, 3)` doesn't make what's inside the parens a tuple. Python's syntax and grammar are documented, and some grammatical rules have higher precedence (function call, list litteral etc).

Comment: I'm still learning the concepts of Python, but a definition of a function as "execution block with parameter wrapped in a tupel" could be fairly correct. I suspect `my_tuple = 1,` is a short-cut which works in some contexts, because Python adds parentheses itself. The more robust syntax seems to be `my_tuple = (1,)`

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz don't waste time "supposing". There's a formal definition of Python's grammar, you just have to read it.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [208]: a = (1)

In [209]: type(a)
Out[209]: int

In [210]: a = (1,)

In [211]: type(a)
Out[211]: tuple

In [212]: a = (1,2)

In [213]: type(a)
Out[213]: tuple

In [214]: a = [1]

In [215]: type(a)
Out[215]: list

In [216]: a = [1,]

In [217]: type(a)
Out[217]: list
```