# Why parenthesis are needed in tuples?

Tags: python

Some time ago I thought that the tuple's constructor was a pair of parentheses `()`.

Example:

```
>>> (1, )
(1, )
>>> type((1, ))
<type 'tuple'>
>>> t = (1, )
>>> type(t)
<type 'tuple'>
```

But now I know that it is the comma `,`.

So, doing the same as above:

```
>>> 1,
(1,)
>>> type(1,)
<type 'int'>  # Why?
>>> 1,2,3
(1,2,3)
```

But if I do:

```
>>> type(1,2,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: type() argument 1 must be string, not int
```

This makes sense to me, but:

```
>>> t = 1,2,3
>>> type(t)
<type 'tuple'>
```

And finally:

```
>>> type((1,2,3))
<type 'tuple'>
```

Here's the question: why are parenthesis needed in the final case if the tuple is just `1,2,3`?

Comment: type(1,2,3) may confuse python because `,` are used to separate parameters. So it may think that 1 is the first parameter, 2 is the second and so on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017811/when-are-parentheses-required-around-a-tuple

Comment: What about `type(())`? That returns `tuple`.

Comment: @JakeGriffin You are right, I missed that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because sometimes without the parentheses the expression would be ambiguous: without them, you are making a function call with three arguments. Since some functions do need to take three arguments, a different representation is needed to express a single three-element tuple argument. As it happens, `type()` can be called with one or three arguments. In the latter case the first argument must be a classname, so it complains when it sees an integer.

Answer (score 6):

In some contexts, commas have another meaning - for example, inside the parentheses of a function call, they separate the parameters.  Putting a set of parentheses around your tuple guarantees that it's in a simple expression context, where the commas are interpreted as tuple element separators.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that t *is* (1,2,3):

```
>>> t = 1,2,3
>>> t
(1, 2, 3)
>>> type(t)
<class 'tuple'>
```

And that `t = 1,2,3` is syntactic sugar for the explicitly parenthesized version, a form of sugar that is especially nice for tuple-unpacking.

Answer (score 1):

You call [type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) with three ints, which does not match the expected arguments for either overloaded implementation.

Comment: That case makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Because without the parenthesis, the [type()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#type) built-in function will interpretate you are given three parameters instead one.

According to [python official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#type), type() may accepts one or three parameters:

- type(object)
- type(name, bases, dict)

And with parenthesis you provide just one parameter, a tuple object, which will not cause a error.