# Tuple declaration in Python

Tags: python, tuples, immutability, cpython, packing

In python, one can declare a tuple explicitly with parenthesis as such:

```
>>> x = (0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)
>>> x
(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)
>>> type(x)
<type 'tuple'>
```

Alternatively, without parenthesis, python automatically packs its into a immutable tuple:

```
>>> x = 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25
>>> x
(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)
>>> type(x)
<type 'tuple'>
```

**Is there a pythonic style to declare a tuple?** If so, please also reference the relevant PEP or link.

There's no difference in the "end-product" of achieving the tuple but **is there a difference in how the tuple with and without parenthesis are initialized (in CPython)?**

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017811/when-are-parentheses-required-around-a-tuple. (There isn't any difference - the commas define the tuple, parentheses are optional but often useful.)

Comment: Whoops wrong it should be `CPython`

Comment: Hmm...I'd prefer `x = (0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)` because it's clear that *`x` is a tuple.* And that's more like *a real tuple (I mean, like the output).*

Comment: Err sorry I had closed it as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017811/when-are-parentheses-required-around-a-tuple but it's not really. And Nikita's answer is the right one.

Answer (score 5):

From practical point of view it's best to always use parenthesis as it contributes to readability of your code. As one of the `import this` moto says:

> "Explicit is better then implicit."

Also remember, that when defining one-tuple you need a comma: `one_tuple = (15, )`.

Comment: The point on one element tuple is not correct. `x = 1,; x` gives `(1,)`

Comment: @alvas: Nikita says that: *When defining one-tuple you need a comma.* Not about the parenthesis.

Comment: @KevinGuan Ah, I misunderstood.

Comment: `x=1,` and `x=(1,)` both legal tuples, `type(x)` will give `<class 'tuple'>`. But `x=1` and `x=(1)` are just integers, `type(x)` will give `<class 'int'>` here.

Comment: And a _zero_ element tuple needs the parens: `()`.

Comment: Interesting `(,)` is illegal to declare a zero tuple.

Answer (score -1):

There's no particular "pythonic" way. Except for the empty parenthesis the parenthesis is just a parenthesis (which controls precedence). That is the expression `x = 1,2,3` is same as `x = (1,2,3)` (as the tuple is created before assignment anyway).

Where it may differ is where the order matters. For example if `l` is a list or tuple the expression `1,2,l.count(1)` would mean that `l.count` is called before the tuple is created while `(1,2,l).count(1)` first creates the tuple then it's `count` is called. It's the same parenthesis as in `(2+3)*4` (which says add first and multiply then).

The only case where the parenthesis is required is when creating the empty tuple. This is done by fx the expression `x = ()` because there's no other way. And the only case where trailing comma is mandatory is when creating a tuple of length one (ie `x = 1,`) since it would be impossible to distinguish from the element `1` otherwise.