# Python convert named string fields to tuple

Tags: python, tuples

Similar to this question: [Tuple declaration in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809173/tuple-declaration-in-python)

I have this function:

```
def get_mouse():
    # Get: x:4631 y:506 screen:0 window:63557060
    mouse = os.popen( "xdotool getmouselocation" ).read().splitlines()
    print mouse
    return mouse
```

When I run it it prints:

```
['x:2403 y:368 screen:0 window:60817757']
```

I can split the line and create 4 separate fields in a list but from Python code examples I've seen I feel there is a better way of doing it. I'm thinking something like `x:=` or `window:=`, etc.

I'm not sure how to properly define these "named tuple fields" nor how to reference them in subsequent commands?

I'd like to read more on the whole subject if there is a reference link handy.

Comment: Do you mean a dictionary? Such as `dict([('x',1234),('y',368),('screen',0),('window',60817757)])`

Comment: how's the `get_mouse` function to do with your question? Please be focus on what you need

Comment: Just a note, it seems you may be using Python 2, which is no longer supported! You should make the switch to Python 3.

Comment: @LPython Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't hit EOL until 2021 and it supports Python 2.17 and Python 3.5. I'm trying to support Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 and Gnome 3.18 to 3.22+ in the same program. I use a lot of `try:` and `except:` statements. It will get worse when I try to support Windows 10 and WSL2 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it would be a better option to use a dictionary here. Dictionaries allow you to set a key, and a value associated to that key. This way you can call a key such as `dictionary['x']` and get the corresponding value from the dictionary (if it exists!)

```
data = ['x:2403 y:368 screen:0 window:60817757'] #Your return data seems to be stored as a list
result = dict(d.split(':') for d in data[0].split()) 

result['x']
#'2403'
result['window']
#'60817757'
```

You can read more on a few things here such as;

[Comprehensions](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html)

[Dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

Happy learning!

Comment: Looks good, except substitute `mouse` for `result`. Sorry it seemed obvious to me the function was getting the screen x,y coordinates where the mouse pointer is. It seems a unique situation and not so obvious to others.

Comment: You can rename the variables however you like, just take note on the comprehension performed and how calls to the dictionary are made. These are the two key elements to how this functions.

Comment: Although default, I find `for d in data[0].split(' '))` more readable. Thank you for your answer and the bonus reading links.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
dict(mouse.split(':') for el in mouse
```

This should give you a dict (rather than tuples, though dicts are mutable and also required hashability of keys)

```
{x: 2403, y:368, ...}
```

Also the `splitlines` is probably not needed, as you are only reading one line. You could do something like:

```
mouse = [os.popen( "xdotool getmouselocation" ).read()]
```

Though I don't know what `xdotool getmouselocation` does or if it could ever return multiple lines.

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `dict(mouse.split(':') for el in mouse[0].split())` (assuming `mouse` always has one element; I agree the `splitlines` is redundant). Also, the values of the dictionary would be strings instead of integers.

Comment: `.splitlines()` was a carry over from copied function `wmctrl` which populated list of all windows. I thought of taking it out but reconsidered based on the fact `xdotool` might return more than one line if there was errors. Granted there should only be one mouse location but who knows. Can you elaborate on "mutability" and "hashability of keys" a bit? Putting into a `dict` seems very simple but how does one read a dictionary?