# What does this list contain?

Tags: python, string, list, element

If there is a list like this:

```
lst  = [('this', 4, 3), ('that', 9, 3), ('those', 2, 6)]
```

> **What every element of this list is?**

'this' - is a string

4 - is an integer

And this?  ('this', 4, 3)

Comment: [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708510/python-list-vs-tuple-when-to-use-each

Comment: A list which contains 3 tuples.

Comment: You could have iterated over the list can called `print(type(x))` to find out what they were

Answer (score 2):

It is a `tuple`. A tuple is a sequence of immutable Python objects. Tuples are sequences, just like lists. The differences between tuples and lists are, the tuples cannot be changed unlike lists and tuples use parentheses, whereas lists use square brackets.

Comment: Technically, tuples don't exactly get made by parentheses. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16017811/10077