# Python3: in __getitem__ implementation distinguish Foo[1,2] from Foo[(1,2)]

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there the possibility in Python 3 to distiguish the item lookups Foo[(1,2)] and Foo[1,2]? Since in

```
class Foo:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print(type(key), key)

foo = Foo()
foo[(1,2)]
foo[1,2]
```

both produce the same output.

```
<class 'tuple'> (1, 2)
```

---

Edit: On why I want that: I have a set of Classes that are "parameterized" and I wanted to implent a factory for those classes. e.g. `__call__(*arg)` to instanciate the class with the parameters inferred from `*arg` and `__getitem__` to return the class that with the parameters passed via the key.

I hoped that `__getitem__` might be used similar to `__call__` in the way that you can distinguish `foo[(1,2)]` from `foo[1,2]` similar to the way you can distinguish `foo((1,2))` from `foo(1,2)` .

Comment: No, they are exactly equivalent. See what happens: `x = 1,2` and `y = (1,2)` and then you'll see, they are the same. You'd have to do some serious code introspection to do this, and it doesn't make any sense. *Why* do you want to distinguish these in the first place?

Comment: It's the comma `,` that makes a tuple, the parenthesis are actually useless. `1,2` is the same as `(1,2)`. It's just more readable.  Note however that you could distinguish between `[1, 2]` and `[[1,2]]`.

Comment: I wanted to get two different ways to call an object (see my edit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not easily. Although the source is [tokenized](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) differently, the code is eventually parsed the same way:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('foo[(1,2)]')) == ast.dump(ast.parse('foo[1,2]'))
True
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('foo[(1,2)]'))
"Module(body=[Expr(value=Subscript(value=Name(id='foo', ctx=Load()), slice=Index(value=Tuple(elts=[Num(n=1), Num(n=2)], ctx=Load())), ctx=Load()))])"
```

There are two ways I can think of to detect the difference, both insane:

- Get in before the parser does, by [registering a custom codec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) to use in the coding declaration.
- Use [introspection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) to find the original source code, and check in there for the parens.

A related question concerning the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html): [When are parentheses required around a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16017811/674039)

Comment: I see that is unfortunate... I would prefer that __getitem__ would have simlar properties to __call__