# What's the difference between 'r = yield n' and 'r = (yield n)'？

Tags: python, python-3.x, coroutine

I was learning coroutine and tried some tutorial, I found this code.

```
>>> def g(n):
...     while n >= 0:
...         r = (yield n)
...         if r:
...             n = r
...         else:
...             n -= 1
```

I asked myself why there was `r = (yield n)`, then I modified the code as below,

```
>>> def f(n):
...     while n >= 0:
...         r = yield n
...         if r:
...             n = r
...         else:
...             n -= 1
...
>>>
```

After that I guessed that when `send(value)` called, `r = yield n` would return value, and `r = (yield n)` would return a tuple, like (value,).

So I tested the code separately, the result is :

```
>>>
>>> gc = g(5)
>>> gc.send(None)
5
>>> type(gc.send(4))
<class 'int'>
>>>

>>> fc = f(5)
>>> fc.send(None)
5
>>> fc.send(4)
4
>>> type(fc.send(4))
<class 'int'>
```

Both results were 'int' type, not a tuple type.
I am really confused, what's the deffierence between the 2 codes?
It seemed there were no difference at all.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference, which you can verify directly with the [parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse):

```
>>> source1 = "r = (yield n)"
>>> source2 = "r = yield n"
>>> import ast
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse(source1))
"Module(body=[Assign(targets=[Name(id='r', ctx=Store())], value=Yield(value=Name(id='n', ctx=Load())))])"
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse(source2))
"Module(body=[Assign(targets=[Name(id='r', ctx=Store())], value=Yield(value=Name(id='n', ctx=Load())))])"
```

You could also reach the same conclusion, in a more roundabout way, by checking the [disassembly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) of `f` and `g`.

Non-empty tuples require commas, see *[When are parentheses required around a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16017811/674039)*

Answer (score 1):

> It seemed there were no difference at all.

You are correct -- there is no difference at all.

The `r = (yield n)` assignment simply has some redundant parens.
It is much like assigning `four = 1 + (1 + 1) + 1`; the parens don't changing anything.

If you want a 1-tuple, use a comma:

```
>>> r = 6,
>>> r
(6,)
```

Feel free to tack on parens, like `(6,)`,
if you feel you should call attention to the fact that your expression is a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Parenthesis tells the interpreter to compute this statement first. When the interpreter reads `r = yield n`, it will compute `yield n` first, and then assign it to r. It already computes yield n first, so there is no need for parenthesis. If you wanted to make it a tuple, you can use this code `r = (yield n,)`