# Tuple comparison gives different result with and without explicit parenthesis

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was comparing two tuples for equality using below expression.

```
>>> (1, 2, 3) == 1, 2, 3
(False, 2, 3)
```

I was expecting it will give `True`. However, below expression works as expected.

```
>>> a = (1, 2, 3)
>>> b = 1, 2, 3
>>> 
>>> a == b
True
```

I am unable to understand this behavior. I am using Python 3.6.8

Comment: Useful reading: [When are parentheses required around a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017811/when-are-parentheses-required-around-a-tuple)

Comment: this can produce some visually bizarre results, such as `1, 2, 3 == 1, 2, 3  >>>  (1, 2, False, 2, 3)`

Answer (score 3):

The `(1, 2, 3) == 1, 2, 3` is defining a tuple where the first element is the value of the expression `(1, 2, 3) == 1`, which is False.